# pyserial dropping data in long sequence

Tags: python, pyserial, uart

I am creating a string of binary data using pack.

When writing the data over serial, the data is not making it past 0x270F, while the size of the data is 0x3C85.

```
pbSerial = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbserial-FTE4QLXM', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=None)
#Code to create binarySequence here using pack
num = pbSerial.write(binarySequence)
```

In this case, variable num returns the proper length, 0x3C85. Analyzing the actual output on the uart, it does not make it past 0x270F bytes. Is this limit documented anywhere?

In the mean time, I am using this, which works correctly:

```
for i in range (0, len(binarySequence)):
    pbSerial.write(binarySequence[i])
```

Comment: try using a lower baud rate maybe? that is a really long serial string... what are you doing with it?

Comment: lowering the baud rate to 9600 I receive 0x2D70 chars. Then I tried again with 115200 and received 0x2DF0. The amount transmitted is not always consistent.

Comment: I dont know thats a whole lotta data to be shoving over in one pass ... just chunk it up and send it in parts

Comment: How are you analysing the output of serial port? Is this on Linux, Windows or Mac? I noticed you don't have flowcontrol enabled, Any chance the device you are talking to needs some sort of flowcontrol??

Comment: What is at the other end of the serial connection that is receiving the data? Are you using any flow control? It's possible you're overrunning the receive buffer on the receiving side, and it's dropping bytes. Do you have a way to do a comparison of the data sent against the data received to find out if you're receiving the first 0x2df0 bytes correctly and the rest are truncated, or is it droping bytes here and there?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Not using flow control. Analyzing by having the serial out going to serial in on different port, viewing using coolterm. It is truncated. All data prior to ending is accurate, packets are not being lost or framing issues.

Comment: Then try to send chunks of data out instead of the whole amount at once.

Comment: You output settings look good, but what are the settings of the receiving end?  As a test, inject some delay after each 100 bytes or so and see if it is a throughput issue.  My money is on the receiving end not having a fast or large enough buffer.  You have no flow control and the receiving end can't cope.